# jquery + css: enlighten buttons?

Tags: jquery, css

how can I implement the "enlightening" effect, I can see in the "Tags" section in this website ?

http://dribbble.com/shots/37765-Walken-on-Water-Halfsies?list=index

I would like to not just change color (gray to white) of the background, but to progressively make the button lighter and lighter.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you will have to use `animate()` and `css()` to change the `background` property.

I will point you to this [well-written tutorial](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations/) that explains how you can achieve this.

They even have a [demo page](http://snook.ca/technical/jquery-bg/), I think you're looking for the last example.